# Ruby += operation throws error

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, count, operation

I have a Hash and all values are arrays. So it looks like the following:

```
my_hash = {:key       => ["some string", "some string"],
           :other_key => ["some string"]}
```

Now i want the count of all strings in this hash.

So i do:

```
my_hash.each_value do |value|
  string_count += value.count
end
```

But I get the Error: `undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass`

But my value array is never nil...
For example when I do:

```
my_hash.each_value do |value|
  puts value.count
end
```

I get:

```
2
1
2
2
2
etc.
```

So what am I doing wrong?
Thx in Advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to initialize `string_count` before loop.

```
string_count = 0
my_hash.each_value do |value|
  string_count += value.count
end
```

Answer (score 4):

"inject" is the method for this:

```
string_count = my_hash.inject(0) { |memo, (key, value)| memo += value.count }
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject

Comment: `value` is in fact a pair, you should unpack it `(key, value)`

Comment: ah! I'd not spotted the "each_value" in the OP (assumed "each"). Edited to reflect correction. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`string_count` is `nil`.

```
string_count = 0
my_hash.each_value do |value|
  string_count += value.count
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Is *string_count* ever initialized?
(Do you have "string_count = 0" in your code?)

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize string_count first.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing `string_count` prior to the iterator will solve this problem.

```
string_count = 0

my_hash.each_value do |value|
  string_count += value.count
end

#=> 3
```